# How to link one frame out of a nested Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe within an iframe. So Iframe-2 is within Iframe-1.

How do I link from iframe-2 to iframe-1 without going all the way out to parent window and then clicking to reopening iframe-1?

Answer (score 0):

window.parent.location.href = \"target_link";

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).